# Использование PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Подскажите пожалуйста решение следующей проблемы:
создаю прайс-лист в формате MS Excel (xlsx) при помощи PHPExcel. Для этого в предварительно созданный файл шаблона прайс-листа (собственно говоря в шаблоне только шапка и настроены поля, шрифт и т.д.) записываю данные, далее дополнительно применяю стили (границы ячеек и т.д.) и сохраняю файл под другим именем на сервере. Код работает нормально, НО, в режиме предварительного просмотра перед печатью вижу абсолютно пустые страницы, кол-во которых равно кол-ву созданных страниц??? В коде я не обращаюсь к ячейкам подобных листов? Свойства листа и прочее установлены правильно. Почему "на выходе" получаются пустые листы (еще раз, их число соответствует кол-ву заполненных данными листов)?

Comment: а на печати то что? я ведь правильно понял, что документ заполняется, но текста не видно только в предварительном просмотре? область печати то корректно отмечена?

Comment: Я, естественно, на печать не отправлял, но в предварительном просмотре ровно в два раза больше листов (именно печатных). Что интересно, нижний колонтитул (страница из страниц) есть на всех листах, сквозная строка (ну, нумерация заголовков) только на заполненных листах ??? Вот выбрал я из базы товаров, которые вместились в 50 страниц, а имею 100 ??? Пятьдесят из них пустые. Кол-во выбранных записей из БД совпадает с кол-вом строк в листе Excel. Т.е. мой php-код вообще не обращается к этим листам ??? Там полностью пусто. Последним обращением к ячейкам есть установка границ ячеек (сетки таблицы).

Answer (score 1):

Пришел к выводу, что PHPExcel самостоятельно, после записи данных в файл-шаблон и сохранении его как нового файла, меняет границы (ширину) листа. Это видно в режиме разметки страницы (в Excel) - появляются новые границы и захватывается столбец из соседнего листа (в шаблоне все нормально, код php ничего не меняет). Отсюда и появление новых пустых страниц для печати. Решилось все банально просто - установил область печати перед сохранение файла $page->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('A1:E' . $row);.